# How to send a 6-km mirror close to the Sun to propel a light sail?

Tags: propulsion

I have written a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.11474) about a crewed interstellar spacecraft that I propose.

I suggest to use either a laser, a Fresnel lens or a mirror to propel the sail of the spacecraft with sunlight.

I have calculated a size of around 6 kilometers for the lens or mirror if they are placed at the closest distance that the Parker Solar Probe will reach.

I haven't laid out many specific details about this in my paper so, I wanted to ask:

For a Fresnel lens, what type of material do you think that would be needed?

For the case of a mirror, I calculate a mass of around 700 tons (if the primary mirror of the James Webb telescope is used).

I guess it would have to be built in orbit but, what do you suggest to send such structure close to the Sun? Ion thrusters?

I'm not sure if my paper is enough to see what I have in mind, so [these](https://youtu.be/JEf7Z_TLmgU) animations might make it a lot easier.

Comment: I am not sure that getting your lens or mirror closer to the Sun will help. There is such a thing as [conservation of Etendue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etendue) Here are some ways to get the idea of this concept; go outside with a magnifying glass and try to focus or concentrate blue sky, or walk towards a wall and see if it gets brighter.

Comment: Interesting. I'm assuming that the closer to the Sun, the higher the irradiance. Inverse-square law would be addessed with flexible mirrors that change their orientation over time. Divergence would be contionously reduced over time. But my doubt is more about how to send such structure that far.

Comment: Think about what you would see if you were on board the "sailing" spacecraft, however many AU distant from the Sun. How would your mirror look in comparison to the Sun itself? And, how much do you suppose the light reflected by the mirror would help in comparison to the light coming from the Sun itself?

Comment: The irradiance goes up because from the mirror's point of view the Sun gets larger! Per unit solid angle it stays about the same brightness. This is why I recommended that you "walk towards a wall and see if it gets brighter." It doesn't, but your "the higher the irradiance." still applies. You get more total light, but for a given solid angle it stays about the same, it just gets bigger and subtends a larger angle.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is well outside "mainstream" engineering or science.

Comment: thanks for your answers!